# SwiftUI, MVVM and combine, how to retrieve data

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, combine

I am building a SwiftUI app and cannot get my head around the implementation of the MVVM mechanism. I am an Android dev and switch to Apple dev few months ago for personal project.

I am just building a feed like most of social app.

My View is as below:

```
@ObservedObject private var viewModel = FeedViewModelImpl()
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    let listOfPosts: [FeedItemEntity] = viewModel.getFeed()
                    ForEach(listOfPosts) { post in
                        PostItemView(item: post)
                    }
                }
            }
```

The ViewModel implemented is as below:

```
final class FeedViewModelImpl: ObservableObject, FeedViewModel {

    @Published var feed: [FeedItemEntity]
    
    @Published var state: FeedState = .na
    @Published var hasError: Bool = false

    var feedUseCase: FeedUseCase
    
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        self.feedUseCase = FeedUseCaseImpl.shared
        setupErrorSubscription()
    }
    
    func getFeed() {
        feedUseCase
            .getFeed()
            .sink { res in
                switch res {
                case .failure(let err):
                    self.state = .failure(error: err)
                default:
                    break
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] feedsValue in
                self?.feed = feedsValue
                self?.state = .success
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
}
```

I do not understand how I pass the data between the `viewModel` call to the View. On Android, you build an `obervable` loop on the UI and wait for the event to be triggered. But I cannot see how to do it on SwiftUI. I think I am missing a part.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: you probably can't your head around it because MVVM makes no sense in SwiftUI because the `View` struct is already a view model so MVVM view model objects just won't work, will cause slow downs and crashes. It's better to put the effort in to learn the View struct hierarchy , body func, @State and @Binding.

Answer (score -1):

You currently have `let listOfPosts: [FeedItemEntity] = viewModel.getFeed()` which doesn't make sense because `getFeed()` function in your view model doesn't return anything.

I would suggest that you call `self.getFeed()` in the init of the ViewModel so it updates your `@Published` feed. Since you're using `.sink`, the value of `feed` will update whenever there are changes.

Now in your view, you can directly use `viewModel.feed`:

```swift
ForEach(self.viewModel.feed) { post in
  PostItemView(item: post)
}
```

Whenever the `@Published` properties in an ObservableObject change, the views redraw automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try this common approach, using the `FeedViewModelImpl` published `feed`
in your `ForEach`, and fetch the data in `.onAppear {...}`.

Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Note, I would recommend using the async/await concurrency framework instead of using
`Combine` to fetch data from a server.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FeedViewModelImpl() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <-- here (NavigationView is deprecated)
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.feed) { post in  // <-- here
                        PostItemView(item: post)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.getFeed()  // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```